# Switch Image By Adding Text Before File Extension

Tags: javascript

I Hope you can help me.

When I click button it adds night before file extension ex.(interior-1.jpg to interior-1-night) but it only affects the first image which is interior-1.jpg.
What I want is to add "night" text before the file extension of all images under the "image" ID.

Here is my html code

```
<button onclick="changeMode()">switch</button>
<img id="image" src="interior-1.jpg"/>
<img id="image" src="interior-2.jpg"/>
<img id="image" src="interior-3.jpg"/>
<img id="image" src="interior-4.jpg"/>
<img id="image" src="interior-5.jpg"/>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
<script>
function changeMode() {
var filename = document.getElementById("image").src;
var modfilename = filename.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '-night$1');
document.getElementById("image").src = modfilename;
</script>
}
```

Comment: The `id` selector must be provided for a single HTML element. What you're looking for is `class`, which can be given to multiple HTML elements, and then you can use `document.getElementsByClassname` to fetch all instances of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **never** use same `id` name on elements in the dom. Instead use same `class` name. To apply the src on all the `img` tag get all the tags using `document.getElementsByClassName`. Iterate over each element and change the src using a `forEach` loop

```js
function changeMode() {
  var filename = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
  var a = '';
  Object.values(filename).forEach((e) => {
    a = e.src;
    var modfilename = a.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '-night$1');
    e.src = modfilename;
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeMode()">switch</button>
<img class="image" src="interior-1.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="interior-2.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="interior-3.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="interior-4.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="interior-5.jpg" />
```

Comment: thank you so much bro this code works for me. another question bro, what will i do to make it toggle? if i click the button it will add "-night" and if i click again it will go back to original filename

Comment: You can toggle the class name for that image, in one class hide the image in the other show it hsjng css disolay property

Comment: is there other way than that?

Comment: You can use .toggle() function of jquery,  and there are many ways of doing it with JS too. They are pretty standard one search will give you results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting your element by `GetElementById` which only returns one element. You should change the `id` tag to `name` like this:

```
<img name="image" src="interior-1.jpg"/>
```

Then you should be able to retrieve all the elements using `var els = document.getElementsByName('image');`

now you need to change their file names, so

```
for (let i = 0; i<els.length; i++){
   els[i].src = els[i].src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '-night$1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents. Use classes. This way you can query multiple elements instead of just one. Then apply your changes to each element using, in this case, a forEach.

The elements returend from `document.querySelectorAll` is a `nodeList`. That's why I use `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.

```js
  

function changeMode() {
    const imageNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(imageNodes,  (node) => {
     let modfilename = node.src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '-night$1');
      node.src = modfilename
    })
    
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeMode()">switch</button>
<img class="image" src="interior-1.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="interior-2.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="interior-3.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="interior-4.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="interior-5.jpg"/>
```